# Cancel setup rollback progress bar in innosetup?

Tags: progress-bar

How to diplay a rollback progress bar when cancel the install process by InnoSetup?

How to write scripts in the .iss file?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Anyone support? not uninstall but when cancel the install process.

Comment: Nobody has this problem? not uninstall but when cancel the install process. I need a rollback progress bar when cancel the install process